# Can I install ubuntu alongside windows WITHOUT dual boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

Basically I want to install Ubuntu for work on my personal desktop without affecting the current windows installation *at all*, without affecting the windows EFI partition for example.

Planning on installing Ubuntu on a separate *internal* SSD and booting into it by choosing the drive through BIOS/UEFI menu, just like how one would boot into a livecd/usb.

Is this possible? How should I approach this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. You simply don't add Windows to the grub boot menu.

Comment: Disconnect the Windows drive either physically or logically in UEFI. Otherwise Ubuntu's Ubquity installer installs to first drive's ESP - efi system partition usually Window's ESP. Or see this: Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379
Or removing boot flag/esp flag from first drive, so only ESP is install drive. 
Or if you have ESP on second or external drive, you can just reinstall grub, either manually or using Boot-Repair's advanced mode & full reinstall to correct drive.

Comment: Okay that's some helpful information. I'll go with logically disconnecting the drive then.

Comment: "Is this possible?"  Yes.  "How should I approach this?" Just as you describe.  I don't see the problem.

Comment: Unplug the Windows disk before proceeding. Install Ubuntu in the same UEFI mode as Windows. Rufus will create a GPT-UEFI only Live USB that will ensure a UEFI install. When install completes, plug in the Windows drive, Boot the Ubuntu drive and run `sudo update-grub` to add Windows to the new drive's grub menu.